# Invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have got this warning, have someone an idea:

`warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\testplanning\modules\planning\planning.module on line 425.`

The code where he the fall is:

```
foreach($stap3[2] as $key => $value) {
    $waardeSoortStage[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the variable `$stap3[2]` is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to do so:

```
foreach($stap3 as $key => $value) {
    $waardeSoortStage[$key] = $value;
}
```

because I think `$stap3` is your array,`$stab3[2]` might only be one member of it.

Answer (score 1):

`$stap3[2]` is not an array or an empty array.

You can check `$stap3[2]` with `is_array($stap3[2])` If is really array it returns true.

Also you can debug it with `var_dump($stap3[2])`